# Can't see Safari developer Timeline's Memory Instrument

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to analyze web app memory usage in a Safari browser. I read in several sites that Safari's Web Inspector Timeline can be used to analyze web app memory, but I don't see a Memory option.  Here's what I see:

[image]

Here are the sites that say I should also have a Memory element:

https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/

https://support.apple.com/guide/safari-developer/improve-memory-performance-dev935efea11/mac

I'm looking for a way to 'turn on' the Memory element.  Or perhaps it is no longer available?  I'd appreciate any pointers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Go to the timelines Tab
2. Go to the left bar (with all the timeline options)
3. Click the 'edit' button to the top right of that bar
4. Click the Memory checkbox to enable it.

Comment: It doesn't list 'Memory' check box for me.
When click on edit button, list contains Network Requests, Layout & Rendering, JavaScript & Events

Comment: I just noticed that the section doesn't scroll. You have to expand the dev tools by dragging the entire section up - then after you click the pencil icon you'll see "Media & Animations", "Memory", and "JavaScript Allocations" as checkable items