# Can't see Safari's Web Inspector 'Memory' Timeline

Tags: memory-leaks, safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to analyse memory usage of a web app using web inspector.
But it doesn't have a section called 'Memory' in Timelines as described in this article https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/

I also tried this solution [Can't see Safari developer Timeline's Memory Instrument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465464/cant-see-safari-developer-timelines-memory-instrument/48739697#comment91064031_48739697)
but it doesn't get listed in the edit list as well

Available options are

- Network Requests
- Layout & Rendering
- JavaScript & Events